# Big O simplification of factorial

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

To calculate BigO and constant for the following function :
I have don't know how to simplify it further. Any advise ? Thx

```
 T(n) =  (n!n+n^3)(n^2+7logn)      
      <= (n!n+n^3)(n^2 +7n)   (since n>= log n)
      <= (n!n+n^3)(n^2 +7n)    (n^3 >= 7n if n > 3) 
      <= (n!n+n^3)(n^2 + n^3)   
      <= (n!n+n^3)(n!n + n^3)  (n!n >= n^2)    
         :
```

Comment: hi Simon, have you tried your luck on [Computer Science Stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highest-order term can be found by expanding:

```
 T(n) =  (n!n+n^3)(n^2+7logn) 
      =  n!n^3 + 6n!nlogn + n^5 + 7n^3logn
```

At this point we can simply compare terms and see which one is biggest:

```
n!n^3 vs 6n!nlogn
since n^2 > 7logn for n >= 4, n!n^3 > 7n!nlogn for n >= 1

n!n^3 vs n^5
since n! > n^2 for n >= 4, n!n^3 > n^5 for n >= 4

n!n^3 vs 7n^3logn
since n! > 7logn for n >= 4, n!n^3 > 7n^3logn for n >= 4
```

Based on all this, for n >= 4,

```
 T(n) =  (n!n+n^3)(n^2+7logn) 
      =  n!n^3 + 6n!nlogn + n^5 + 7n^3logn
     <=  n!n^3 + n!n^3 + n!n^3 + n!n^3
      = 4n!n^3
      = O(n!n^3)
```

If you want to find another expression that bounds n!n^3 that's well and good, but I'd recommend another question for that.

Comment: how to get 6n!logn and 6n^3logn ?  Thx

Comment: I think your `6`'s are supposed to be `7`s and `6n!logn` is supposed to be `7*n!*n*logn`.

Comment: @SimonLeung I edited to fix some typos that you and/or walnut pointed out. Please see if this makes more sense.